# What are the alternatives to eval in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, eval

I wrote the following recursive function in order to parse some settings and correctly populate some log file objects I have.

When I run this code against Code Climate it tells me that (of course) the use of `eval` is not encouraged. Is there a way I can rewrite this method so I do not need `eval` and also do not need a `case` statement? Nothing comes to mind.

```
def parse(settings, logfile = nil)
  settings.each do |key, value|
    if value.is_a?(Hash)
      logfile = Logmsg::LogFile.new
      parse(value, logfile)
    else
      eval("logfile.#{key} = value")
    end
  end
end
```

Any ideas?

I am trying the `instance_variable_set` meta-programming method however I am still running into some issues with it. For some reason my tests are all failing now due to

```
Argument Error: comparison of Fixnum with String failed
```

I am still trying to figure that out.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since assignment to an object's attribute is just syntactic sugar for a method call (i.e `obj.foo = bar` is the same as calling the `foo=` method on `obj` with the argument `bar`), use [`Object#public_send`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Object.html#method-i-public_send):

```
logfile.public_send(:"#{key}=", value)
```

In older code you often see `send` instead of `public_send`, but you should use the latter since it will raise an error if you try to call a private method.

Comment: Hah! I wish I had seen your answer after you edited it! It took me a while to find that I had to put an '=' in the method name or it would not find the proper accessor. Anyway! That indeed worked! Thank you very much, I was not aware of this public_send method!